# Arbitrary number of parameters in Assembler (x86, att)

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm creating a function with the following signature:

```
int function_test (char *something, ...);
```

Let's suppose that on *something there's something that will allow me to know how many parameters were passed (just like printf does with '%').

So I store the current parameter number in `%ebx` as a multiple of 4, starting from 8, so I can get `8(%ebp)`, `12(%ebp)`, etc.

How do I do to get the content of that parameter? When I try:

```
movl %ebx(%ebp),variable
```

I get an error(`junk %ebp after register`).

How can I get the content of that parameter? And what would be the syntax to increment its value?

Comment: You should Google "x86 addressing modes", and specifically AT&T syntax. I think you can do something with `(%ebx, %ebp)`, but probably not directly to a `variable` (would need to be another register).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movl (%ebp, %ebx), %eax`. Note you can't have two memory references, so if you want that in `variable` you will have to do it in two steps. To increment obviously use `inc` not `mov`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! And true about the memory references, that I ended up figuring out (the hard way... ;)